# List all tables being used in a function

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL query which should list out all tables being used in a function.
Need help on this.
exmple: Let say Function_name is 'A' and 4 tables are being used in that function(X,V,B,N). Need query which should give me the result as Function name and table names.

I tried below query:

```sql
select distinct
    a.attrelid::regclass AS tbl,
    p.proname AS function_name,
    p.prosrc
FROM   pg_attribute AS a 
---JOIN   pg_type AS t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
JOIN   pg_class AS c ON a.attrelid = c.oid
join   pg_namespace as s on c.relnamespace= s.oid
JOIN   pg_proc AS p ON s.oid = p.pronamespace
where a.attrelid = 'st_cm.p_a_s_m'::regclas
and p.proname='amthng'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what many people would like. The problem is that PostgreSQL stores function bodies as strings (with the exception of new-style SQL functions, where you don't have that problem any more). Now the code could look like this (I am using PL/pgSQL as an example):

```
EXECUTE format('DELETE FROM %I WHERE id = %s', $1, $2);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM laurenz . Uni;
```

In the first case, you have no chance. The table used depends on the function arguments. But the second case is equally hard. You'd have to consider all syntactic variants to reliably identify the table (I introduced extra spaces and capitalized `uni`). And then you must discount comments and string constants:

```
/* complain about SELECT * FROM laurenz.uni */
RAISE NOTICE 'You really shouldn''t SELECT * FROM laurenz.uni';
```

I hope that is enough to discourage you from trying to find a reliable answer to this question.